# UWP app show image from the Local folder in the WebView

Tags: c#, html, windows, webview, uwp

I am working on a UWP app that supports both Windows 8.1 and 10. There I have a WebView to which I set some html generated in the code using NavigateToString. There I need to show some images which are in the Appdata folder e.g. AppData\Local\Packages\1bf5b84a-6650-4124-ae7f-a2910e5e8991_egahdtqjx9ddg\LocalState\c9dfd4d5-d8a9-41c6-bd08-e7f4ae70e423\4f31f54f-1b5b-4812-9463-ba23ea7988a0\Images

I have tried using ms-appdata:///local/ , file:/// , forward slashes, back slashes everything in the img src. But none of them are loading the images.

Since the above path is too long, I have a sample image at AppData\Local\Packages\1bf5b84a-6650-4124-ae7f-a2910e5e8991_egahdtqjx9ddg\LocalState\1.png and trying to access it in different ways and none of them are showing that image in the web view. But I can access that from a browser.
And if I give a http url for the img src in the below code it works.

Please let me know how I can show images in the LocalState folder in a WebView.

e.g 1.

```
string figures = "<figure><img src=\"ms-appdata:///local/1.png\" alt =\"aaa\" height=\"400\" width=\"400\"/><figcaption>Figure  : thumb_IMG_0057_1024</figcaption></figure>";
procedureWebView.NavigateToString(figures);
```

e.g. 2

```
string  figures = "<figure><img src='file:///C://Users//xxx//AppData//Local//Packages//1bf5b84a-6650-4124-ae7f-a2910e5e8991_egahdtqjx9ddg//LocalState//1.png' alt=\"thumb_IMG_0057_1024\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\"/><figcaption>Figure  : thumb_IMG_0057_1024</figcaption></figure>";
```

Answer (score 3):

> Since the above path is too long, I have a sample image at AppData\Local\Packages\1bf5b84a-6650-4124-ae7f-a2910e5e8991_egahdtqjx9ddg\LocalState\1.png and trying to access it in different ways and none of them are showing that image in the web view.

WebView holds a web context,which won't have access to WinRT API or using WinRT Scheme.

But you can convert the Image to Base64 [DataUri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) and pass it to your webview. For details about converting a picture to Base64 DataUri you can refer to [Reading and Writing Base64 in the Windows Runtime](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/11/reading-and-writing-base64-in-windows.html).

After reading the Blog, I made a [basic demo](https://github.com/elvisxia/WebViewImageSample) and successfully pass the image to webview.
MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private async Task<String> ToBase64(byte[] image, uint height, uint width, double dpiX = 96, double dpiY= 96)
{
    var encoded = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, encoded);
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, height, width, dpiX, dpiY, image);
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    encoded.Seek(0);

    var bytes = new byte[encoded.Size];
    await encoded.AsStream().ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}

private async Task<String> ToBase64(WriteableBitmap bitmap)
{
    var bytes = bitmap.PixelBuffer.ToArray();
    return await ToBase64(bytes, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight);
}

private async void myBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    StorageFile myImage = await GetFileAsync();

    ImageProperties properties = await myImage.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
    WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)properties.Width, (int)properties.Height);
    bmp.SetSource(await myImage.OpenReadAsync());
    String dataStr=await ToBase64(bmp);
    String fileType = myImage.FileType.Substring(1);
    String str = "<figure><img src=\"data:image/"+myImage.FileType+";base64,"+dataStr+"\" alt =\"aaa\" height=\"400\" width=\"400\"/><figcaption>Figure  : thumb_IMG_0057_1024</figcaption></figure>";

    myWebView.NavigateToString(str);
}

private async Task<StorageFile> GetFileAsync()
{
    StorageFile myImage = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myImage.jpg");
    return myImage;
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <WebView Name="myWebView" Width="500"  Height="500" ></WebView>
        <Button Name="myBtn" Click="myBtn_Click">Click Me to Load WebView</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And here is the output:
[image]